# Question on different definitions of principal bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology

I know that there are already a few questions on math.stackexchange where equivalent definitions of principal bundles are discussed, but I could not the find the answer to my question there.

So, the question is: Are the following two definitions equivalent?

Throughout, $G$ is a Hausdorff topological group, $E$ and $B$ are Hausdorff spaces. If possible, I would like to assume no other regularity properties.

**Definition 1:**
A $G$-*principal bundle* is a continuous map $\pi:E\to B$, together with a (right) action of $G$ on the total space such that

1a. Each $x\in B$ has an open neighborhood $U\subseteq B$ such that there is a homeomorphism $\phi\colon \pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times G$ such that $\pi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is just the projection on the first factor.

1b. For each $x\in B$ the fibre $\pi^{-1}(\{x\})$ is invariant under the group action.

1c. For each $x\in B$ and each $y\in\pi^{-1}(\{x\})$, the orbit map $G\to \pi^{-1}(\{x\}) : g \mapsto y.g$ is a homeomorphism.

**Definition 2:**
A $G$-*principal bundle* is a continuous map $\pi:E\to B$, together with a (right) action of $G$ on the total space such that

2a. For each $x\in B$ the fibre $\pi^{-1}(\{x\})$ is invariant under the group action.

2b. Each $x\in B$ has an open neighborhood $U\subseteq B$ such that there is a homeomorphism $\phi\colon \pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times G$ such that for all $x\in\pi^{-1}(U)$ and all $g\in G$ we have $\phi(x.g) = (\pi(x), (p_2(\phi(x)))\cdot g)$, where $p_2:U\times G\to G$ is just the projection on the second factor.

I think I can show that Defintion 2 implies Definition 1, but I have problems showing the converse implication. The problem is that the local trivialization in Def1 does not have to be compatible with the group action. And the homeomorphisms in 1c depend on the elements $x$ and $y$ and it is not clear how they vary.
I think I can -- given Definition1 - construct a continuous $G$-invariant bijection as required in Def2, but I do not see why this should be an open map (unless our spaces are very nice and we can use some open compactness arguemnt or some mapping theorem or invariance of domain or something...)

Answer (score 0):

What about $G= (\bf Q; +)$, $E=\bf R$. Of course, $\bf E : \bf Q$ is a rather strange space, but by definition of the quotient topology, it satisfies your axiom 1.a. And all sections $\bf Q \to \bf R$  defined by $x\to q+ x_0$ are homeomorphisms.  2b is a much stronger axiom

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but do you also know an example where the base space is Hausdorff? Unfortunately, R/Q is not...

Comment: and independently of the Hausdorff question, I do not see how your example satisfies 1a, as the space R is not locally homeomorphic to Q times R/Q ...

Comment: You are right my example was not an example.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to modify your idea and take E to be a Banach space, G to be a closed vector subspace and B=E/G. This time this should be Hausdorff. Unfortunately, I think this satisfies both Definitions, so it is also not a counter-example...